# How do I select right washer/dryer spacer for my Bosch Series 6 washer?

Tags: dryer, washer, stacked-washer-dryer

I have a Bosch Series 6 washer and I’m looking to get a compatible (stackable) dryer.

[image: washer door label]

I understand these devices should be stackable, but I think in order to do that, a spacer is needed to be put between them. I am lost trying to identify which dryer is same generation as my washer, how to find out if they are stack-compatible and how to find the right spacer part for them.

I noticed that Series 6 might not be clear enough identification, since there are generations to these series and there are different models of each series even within a generation of it. I don’t quite follow how Bosch identifies its products, but here is the front panel of my washer:

[image: front panel of washer]

Is there a way for me to identify which dryer is stack-conpatible with my washer and if I need a spacer part?

Comment: What is the model number of your washer? It should be located on the inside of the door.

Comment: There is a bunch of numbers, but here is the first one: E-Nr: WAT2860BY/07

Comment: If you'll take clear, focused, well lit pictures of the labels of both the washer & dryer, you can [edit] them into the question so people can get all the info they might need from them.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks, I’ve updated the question.

Comment: Good on ya! So many people ask for help, then, when asked for more details just silently disappear. I don't have an answer for you, but I'm sure the extra info will help someone help you.

Answer (score 1):

So I had to learn this myself. The point of the stacking plate is to secure the dryer and stop it from walking off during power cycle where it tumbles around. For this, **the stacking plate has to be directly compatible with the dryer, but not with the washer**. The stacking plate screws into the top of the washer and it doesn't really matter where as long as you get to screw all 4 holes. Width of their devices tends to be the same (592 mm) and with depth, you get a lot of play room, but generally if depth of both devices is within 50 mm margin, you can just screw the stacking plate little further back or forward. Here is the way I've done it:

1. Find dryer that fits your requirements for features, price, etc.
2. Find it's product page on Bosh website and go to Dimensions tab, verify the width is same or lower than your washer and that their depth is within acceptable margin (<50 mm).
3. Go to Manuals tab and open English version of User Manual.
4. Find Installation instructions chapter and look for stacking plate product numbers. The manual will explicitly list product numbers of stacking plates compatible with the dryer.
5. Make sure you can actually buy the stacking plate if it isn't supplied with the dryer.

The stacking plate comes with screws to screw the plate to a washer, so check they are included.